# get and delete in Django framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets

i want to build a ModelViewSet class that recive an id from url for instance

> localhost/id

and based on that id i can either show the object with matching id or delete the object
but im having trouble passing the id in the url
my view is like this:

```
class delete_or_show_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'delete']

    def get_queryset(self,mid):
        #Show the object


    def destroy(self, mid):
        #delete the object
```

and my url is like this

```
router.register('(?P<object_id>\d+)', views.delete_or_show_View, basename='do_stuff')
```

Im getting errors for missing aruguments or that the delete method is not allowed
please if someone can guide me how i can do this properly and explain it will be great
thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
class DeleteOrShowView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['get', 'delete']
```

then update your `urls.py` as

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('show-delete', views.DeleteOrShowView, basename='do_stuff')
```

now you can just pass along with this url when hitting this api
`show-delete/<id>/`

Comment: how it gets the id from the url?
because ve tried what you suggested and im getting 404  like there is no path either for get or delete requests

Comment: Sorry, you can remove the slash in that URL. 
just use 

`router.register('show-delete', views.DeleteOrShowView, basename='do_stuff')`

I have updated the same in the answer.

router follows this format and has id as default look up field when we pass some values after the url followed by a slash.

Comment: thank you it works,
BTW if i want to return a Response that the message has been deleted i need to do write my own destroy function?

Comment: you can customize the `def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` function to add custom messages

Comment: and for the show, i can do the same with `def get_queryset(self)` or `def get_object(self)`?

Comment: if you need to update the queryset with some filters, then you can customize `get_queryset`. 
But in case of getting single object, you do not need to update `get_object`, just passing the ID in URL is enough.

Comment: final question if i want to update in the show function i need to use `get_queryset`
but how i can get the id i passed?

Comment: you can use `self.get_object().id` inside the `get_queryset` function to get the object id